# Spring scheduler job don't start

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, spring-scheduled

I implemented a job to run every minute but it never starts.

This is the module's main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@Import({EventsConfig.class, SchedulingConfig.class})
@EnableScheduling
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ScheduleQueryProperties.class, ScheduleThreadPoolProperties.class})
public class EventsStarter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventsStarter.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        try {
            SSLUtil.turnOffSslChecking();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        SpringApplication.run(EventsStarter.class, args);

    }
}
```

This is my Scheduling class

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class BlockedAccountsAlarmSchedule {

    @Autowired
    private BlockedAccountsAlarmScheduleService blockedAccountsAlarmScheduleService;

    @LogProfiler
    @LogInfo(logResult = true)
    @Scheduled(cron = "${schedule.account.alarm.process-time}")
    @Trace(dispatcher = true)
    public void executeToProcess() {
        log.info("m=execute, msg=Job init");
        this.blockedAccountsAlarmScheduleService.processBlockAccountAlarm();
    }

}
```

bootstrap.yml

```
schedule:
  account:
    alarm:
      process-time: "0 0/1 * * * *"
      thread-pool:
        name-prefix: schedule-job-executor
        core-pool-size: 1
        max-pool-size: 2
        queue-capacity: 1
        use-max-available-processors: false
      query:
        limit-size: 100
        execution-count: 3
        execute-until-end: true
```

Application.yml

```
card-utils:
  activation:
    passwordBySms: false
  occurrence-report:
    upload-limit-days: 3
  account:
    credit:
      minimum-limit: 100
  overlimit:
    fee: 10.00
    percentage: 1.10

schedule:
  account:
    alarm:
      process-time: "0 0/1 * * * *"
      thread-pool:
        name-prefix: schedule-job-executor
        core-pool-size: 1
        max-pool-size: 2
        queue-capacity: 1
        use-max-available-processors: false
      query:
        limit-size: 100
        execution-count: 3
        execute-until-end: true
  integration:
    base-uri: "https://api.conductor.com.br/pier/v2/api"
```

The application starts but the BlockedAccountsAlarmSchedule class
is not called at any time

Comment: I'm a little surprised that the application started, but you can probably solve this by moving the `schedule.account.alarm.process-time` property out of bootstrap.yml and into application.yml.  `application.yml` is where you should persist your application-specific properties, bootstrap.yml is for properties required to bootstrap the spring context.

Comment: @lane.maxwell 
schedule.account.alarm.process-time property is also included in application.yml.

Comment: @lane.maxwell
schedule.account.alarm.process-time property is also included in application.yml.
when i delete from bootstrap.yml i get
Encountered invalid Scheduled method 'executeToProcess': Could not resolve placeholder 'schedule.account.alarm.process-time' in value "${schedule.account.alarm.process-time}"

Comment: Please include your application.yml for us to look at.  Also, note that the way you have the cron configured, this will run every hour at 0 and 1 minutes, e.g. 11:00, 11:01, 12:00, 12:01, ...

Comment: @lane.maxwell Isn't this cron supposed to run every minute?

Comment: You are correct; I misinterpreted it.  A little easier to read option to run every minute, at the zero second, is, `0 * * * * *`